# Error connecting to MongoDB hosted in the cloud, using JDBC

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB hosted in the cloud, using JDBC.
But, the authentication fails.

```
My development environment:

Mac OSX
Eclipse

Drivers:

junit-3.8.1.jar
mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar
mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar
bson-3.2.2.jar


I'm using the driver as suggested by the below url:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/?_ga=1.221045400.1622521490.1456732063

Actually, the drivers are updated by the below dependency declaration, by maven build:

     
    org.mongodb 
    mongodb-driver 
    3.2.2
```

Here is my Java code:

```
private static void test() {


    String url = "mongodb://user:pwd@host:19468/heroku_dbname";
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(url));


    // get handle to "heroku_dbname" database
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("heroku_dbname");


    // get a handle to the "book" collection
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("book");

    // make a document and insert it
    Document doc = new Document("title", "Good Habits")
                   .append("author", "Akbar");

    collection.insertOne(doc);

    // get it (since it's the only one in there since we dropped the rest earlier on)
    Document myDoc = collection.find().first();
    System.out.println(myDoc.toJson());

    // release resources
    mongoClient.close();
}
```

When I execute, I get the following exception:

```
Mar 17, 2016 7:15:31 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[ds019468.mlab.com:19468], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Mar 17, 2016 7:15:31 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=ds019468.mlab.com:19468, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Mar 17, 2016 7:15:33 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ds019468.mlab.com:19468
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='db_userName', source='heroku_dbName', password=, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server ds019468.mlab.com:19468. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "code" : 18, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." }
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:45)
    ... 6 more

Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=ds019468.mlab.com:19468, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='db_userName', source='heroku_dbName', password=, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server ds019468.mlab.com:19468. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "code" : 18, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." }}}]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:369)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.(ClusterBinding.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.(ClusterBinding.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getWriteConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:68)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:219)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:74)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:781)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:764)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:515)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:306)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:297)
    at com.chozhan.test.mongodb.MongoJdbcRemote.test(MongoJdbcRemote.java:64)
    at com.chozhan.test.mongodb.MongoJdbcRemote.main(MongoJdbcRemote.java:43)
```

I'm able to successfully login with the same user id and password through mLab web interface and it's working fine.

But, only JDBC attempt fails.

Can somebody help, what's the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

when you create your client connection you need to add the authentication details.

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user, heroku_dbname, pwd);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(), Arrays.asList(credential));
```

or just update your URL:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://user1:pwd1@host1/?authSource=db1");
```

Comment: Thanks! 


Changed the code to:
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(), Arrays.asList(credential));

        System.out.println("mongoClient: " + mongoClient);
        System.out.println("mongoClient.getAddress(): " + mongoClient.getAddress());

The 2nd System.out... doesn't get executed. Same Exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was sorted out by mLab support. I was using mLab's "web interface user id password". I was suggested to create a 'separate db user id / password' to connect. And it worked with the newly created db user id / password.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to change the URL in `application.properties` from:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://username:password@host:port/database_name
```

To:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://username:password@host:port/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I read that `**MongoDB**` default database is `test`.
In my app, I replaced `host:port` to the URI I got from ***mongodb.com***, it works although the URL doesn't contain a value for `port`.